# I want to refresh treeview with new value

Tags: c#

I use the following code to display xml as a treeview.

Now I want to refresh when I edit xml by using some text box in same window. When I edit and save file using textbox I want to refresh treeview also with that new value.

How can I do it?

I use `treeview1.update();` and `treeview1.refresh();` but it's not working.

I used the following code part:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    XmlDataDocument xmldoc = new XmlDataDocument();
    XmlNode xmlnode ;
    FileStream fs = new FileStream("tree.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    xmldoc.Load(fs);
    xmlnode = xmldoc.ChildNodes[1];
    treeView1.Nodes.Clear();
    treeView1.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(xmldoc.DocumentElement.Name));
    TreeNode tNode ;
    tNode = treeView1.Nodes[0];
    AddNode(xmlnode, tNode);
}

private void AddNode(XmlNode inXmlNode, TreeNode inTreeNode)
{
    XmlNode xNode ;
    TreeNode tNode ;
    XmlNodeList nodeList ;
    int i = 0;
    if (inXmlNode.HasChildNodes)
    {
        nodeList = inXmlNode.ChildNodes;
        for (i = 0; i <= nodeList.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            xNode = inXmlNode.ChildNodes[i];
            inTreeNode.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(xNode.Name));
            tNode = inTreeNode.Nodes[i];
            AddNode(xNode, tNode);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        inTreeNode.Text = inXmlNode.InnerText.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the treeview completely new after saving your changes. In order to reuse your existing code, you could refactor it a bit:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  this.FillTreeView();
}
private void FillTreeView()
{
    XmlDataDocument xmldoc = new XmlDataDocument();
    XmlNode xmlnode ;
    FileStream fs = new FileStream("tree.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    xmldoc.Load(fs);
    xmlnode = xmldoc.ChildNodes[1];
    treeView1.Nodes.Clear();
    treeView1.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(xmldoc.DocumentElement.Name));
    TreeNode tNode ;
    tNode = treeView1.Nodes[0];
    AddNode(xmlnode, tNode);
}
private void AddNode(...) { ... }
```

...and after saving your modifications to the xml file, call `FillTreeView()`:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // [Save changes to file]
  this.FillTreeView();
}
```

Comment: Stephan is right, but please note that the `XmlDataDocument` class is obsolete http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/2406023f-59b4-432b-8e4d-afd551d2f890/ I recommend using the `XmlDocument` class or Linq to XML. For an example of XmlDocument check this answer from young Fang http://forums.asp.net/p/1062335/1528035.aspx